# Using ServiceStack Ormlite with Table Valued Functions

Tags: sql-server, ormlite-servicestack, table-valued-parameters

Is it possible to use ServiceStack Ormlite with Table Valued Functions? It seems to be able to work very well with basic DB types like SP, tables, and views. However I am not sure about TVF.

In the interim I could use direct sql, but would like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this with the SqlList functionality like follows:

```
var results = db.SqlList<dynamic>("select * from dbo.myTVF(@parm1, @dparm2)", new { parm1 = parm1Value, parm2 = parm2Value });
```